# multiple classes and id's in jquery not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is working in firefox and chrome but not in safari. Can anybody tell me if this is the correct way to add multiple classes and id's in jquery?

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.imgLink, .imgLink1, .imgLink2, .imgLink3, .imgLink4, .imgLink5, .imgLink6, 
.imgLink7, .imgLink8, .imgLink9').click(function () {
    var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#theImage, #theImage1, #theImage2, #theImage3, #theImage4, #theImage5, #theImage6, 
#theImage7, #theImage8, #theImage9').attr('src', imgPath);
    return false;
  });
});
```

html for .imgLink

```
<a class="imgLink1" href="http://www.customtie.com/images/press/printwear-11-2013.jpg">Printwear Nov 2013</a>
```

hmtl for #theImage

```
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.customtie.com/images/press/counselor-2-2014.jpg" alt="" width="auto" height="auto">
```

Comment: [It's valid code.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) Define "not working" -- what errors are you seeing, if any?

Comment: You might be better off with using one class for everything clickable and one class for everything to be replaced on a side note.

Comment: There's a carriage return in between `#theImage6` and `
#theImage7`.  Javascript won't be too happy about that.

Comment: the code is used for an image gallery (when you click a text link the corresponding image is displayed in a div) Everything works fine in ff and chrome but in safari the images open in a separate page on their own. @Blazemonger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh... **Classes** are not meant to be used that way. Rather:

```
<a href="images/foo.jpg" data-targetid="1" class="imgLink">FOO</a>
<a href="images/bar.jpg" data-targetid="2" class="imgLink">BAR</a>

<img id="theImage1" src="images/default.jpg" alt="">
<img id="theImage2" src="images/default.jpg" alt="">
```

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

  $('.imgLink').click(function ( e ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
       var targetID = $(this).data('targetid');
       $('#theImage'+ targetID).attr('src', imgPath);
  });

});
```

***|→ [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/mefos/1/edit)***

So basically you add **the same class** to all your *clickables*, and a `data-*` attribute with the number of the image ID suffix you want to target.

<sub>There's also other nice ways (even simpler) to achieve the same, but without seeing some HTML it's blind guessing.</sub>

Comment: thank you for the jsbin demo. I added the html, if possible could you have another look and see if there is a simpler way as you mentioned above, If not I will try and implement the demo you set up

Comment: @user3237758  The HTML you added was nothing new, what you should share is an example of their structure and at least a common parent environment.

Comment: I used the code you provided and its working wonderfully in safari. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would first agree with m90's suggestion that you want to just add a single class to all these elements and select off that.

But I would presume that the issue is the carriage return halfway through your string.  If you want to start a new line, you have to end the first one and then concatenate them together like this:

```js
$('.imgLink, .imgLink1, .imgLink2, .imgLink3, .imgLink4, .imgLink5, .imgLink6,'+ 
  '.imgLink7, .imgLink8, .imgLink9').click(function () {
    var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#theImage, #theImage1, #theImage2, #theImage3, #theImage4, #theImage5, #theImage6, ' +
      '#theImage7, #theImage8, #theImage9').attr('src', imgPath);
    return false;
});
```